# Watchdog Timer doesn't play with input via Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino, embedded, debugging, software, watchdog

I uploaded this very simple sketch to my Arduino Nano Every to isolate a problem I have.

```
#include <avr/wdt.h> //installed from library manager, idk

String user_input;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  wdt_enable(WDTO_2S);
  Serial.println("Reset!");
}

void loop() {
  wdt_reset();
  if (Serial.available() > 0) user_input = Serial.readString();
}
```

It's as I feared.

`if (Serial.available() > 0) user_input = Serial.readString();`

causes watchdog to do a software reset ("*Reset!*" gets printed). I don't know why or how to get around this. I've tried changing baud rate to 9600 bps. There is nothing connected to my board, just the USB cable to the computer.

Mighty frustrating. I think this is the last bug in my project.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Well, it is surely a bug. You are waiting the user to input without kicking the watchdog in the same time, so it is resetting. Don't use the watchdog and you will be fine. Or stop it when waiting for input. Or write your own `readString` which will kick the watchdog while waiting.

Comment: Is this a basic how to code in Arduino problem? Should be asked on Arduino.SE. Although it should not run into watchdog reset, since default timeout for readString() is 1 second and watchdog is set to 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently googling for "arduino nano every watchdog", the first link leads to a solution.

Using `WDTO_2S` is wrong. Or at least it does not work. It will not use 2 second timeout.

Use `WDT_PERIOD_2KCLK_gc` and it should work.

Why, you may ask.

The Nano Every uses a newer larger AVR which is not register compatible with older AVRs. It takes time for every aspect of the HAL to get rewritten to work like it should. And in this case not even the GNU avr-libc does not yet support the ATMega4809 chip, so no help from upstream.

And I believe the library header you are including is not related to Arduino but GNU avr-libc.

So if you want to write Arduino code, stay with what Arduino provides, don't use things from avr-libc directly. At least not for the Mega4809 you have.

Comment: Thank you! Google let me down, I tried looking various permutations of keywords. My gut told me it had to do with me using the ATMega4809 instead of the ATmega328. Great sanity check.

I'm afraid I don't entirely understand the bit about the library header. You're saying Arduino's watchdog library is completely functional for the ATMega4809 but AVR's isn't? Regardless, I've changed my project to use the official Arduino Watchdog library in case I get punished later down the line for not using proper form, according to you :)

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/watchdog/